# Hide iOS Home Indicator on Storyboard in Xcode Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xib, xcode-storyboard

I'm designing a View / View Controller in a Storyboard using Xcode 13 Interface Builder.

I've set the VC's "Simulated Size" to "Freeform" and reduced the height. This hides the upper "notch" and hides the iPhone hardware mask surrounding the view.

But the view is still showing the iPhone X -style home indicator bar at the bottom.

None of the various options in the "Simulated Metrics" of `Size`, `Top Bar`, `Bottom Bar`, and `Appearance` hide the multitasking indicator.

How can I hide that black bar on my view in the Storyboard?

[image: home indicator on Storyboard view]

Note: I just want to hide the indicator at design time in Interface Builder.

Hiding the indicator at runtime is discussed here: [iPhone X hide home indicator on view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692121/iphone-x-hide-home-indicator-on-view-controller)

Comment: After you set it to freeform, Go to another file and then come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting "Simulated Size" to "Freeform," just navigate to another file, then come back.

If that doesn't work, try closing and reopening your project or restarting Xcode.

Probably an Xcode bug, but this forces a refresh.